# AS3 - Access variable in root from class

Tags: actionscript-3, class

How to access a variable in the root timeline from within a class? There is a variable called **myblocks** in the root timeline I need to read the value from.

This is the related class part:

```
package myclasses
{

public final class Bcoder extends EventDispatcher
    {

private function getBlocks():void
        {

            for (var i:int = _getNumBlocks; i--; ){
            // how to get the myblocks value from here?

            }}
```

This is from the root timeline: (ActionScript stands in a keyframe)

```
    import myclasses.Bcoder;
var myblocks:Number=20
```

Comment: Why do you combine timeline AS3 with class AS3? I don't know a lot of AS3, or AS altogether, but it seems a strange thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at this: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?349086-AS3-Question-Accessing-a-main-timeline-variable-from-a-class

Furthermore, I'd like to mention that you should use either timeline coding or use a document class, with preference to the latter because this option is the strength of AS3 and will make your code much more structured.

Answer (score 0):

This is complete nonsense and really bad practice. You should avoid this manner of coding!!!

This is really not OOP and make me think about bad AS1 /2 and 3 combined!!!

However this is possible if you have no class defined in Document properties as main Class.

ex : 
in a foler "com", the class ObjectOnStage.as :

```
package com {
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class ObjectOnStage extends Sprite{

    public function ObjectOnStage() {
                this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,onAddedToStage,false,0,false);
                this.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATED,onActivate,false,0,false);
    }
    public function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void{
                    // will output null for both
            trace("\n       added " + e.target + "\n");
            trace(e.target.parent["nonSense"]);
            trace(e.target.parent["nonsense"]);
        }
    public function onActivate(e:Event):void{
                    // will output the values.
            trace("\n       added " + e.target + "\n");
            trace(e.target.parent["nonSense"]);
            trace(e.target.parent["nonsense"]);
        }
    }

}
```

On frame 1 of the Timeline :

```
import com.ObjectOnStage;
var nonSense:int = 1;
var nonsense:String = "This is a nonsense";
var oos:ObjectOnStage = new ObjectOnStage();
this.addChild(oos);
```

You'd better change the whole script!

Adobe should remove the possibility to write script on the Timeline since the export settings are set to AS3 and the strict mode should be always set to strict mode ON.
Also private constructors will be welcome in order to permit an usage of

```
MyClass.getInstance();
```

This will pemit something like:

```
package com {
public class MyMainObject {
    private static var instanceOfMainObject;
    private function MyMainObject(args:Vector.<String>){
                    // or MyMainObject(...args)
        trace("new Instance of MyMainObject created with " + args.toString());
    }
    public static function main(args:Vector.<String>):void{
        instanceOfMainObject = MyMainObject.getInstance(args);
        trace("arguments.length = " + args.length);
        for(var i:int = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++){
            trace( i + " = " + args[i]);
        }
    }
    public static function getInstance(args:Vector.<String>):MyMainObject{
        var instance:MyMainObject = new MyMainObject(args);
        return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this code throws an Error:

```
1153: A constructor can only be declared public.
```

Perhaps this will be the case in AS4 ???

If I understand it trough your comment you must pass the DisplayObjectContainer where your variables are declared to the class as argument.

Example : 
    in MyClass.as

```
    package com {
    import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    public class MyClass extends EventDispatcher{
        public function MyClass(doc:DisplayObjectContainer) {
            trace(doc["nonSense"]);
            trace(doc["nonsense"]);
            // but this is again not OOP even if you use the "class" KEYWORD.
        }
    }
}
```

on the timeline : 
    var nonSense:int = 1;
    var nonsense:String = "This is a nonsense";
    var mclss:MyClass = new MyClass(this);

Concerning EventDispatcher you can also read [my answer about EventDispatcher here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485526/in-actionscript-3-0-can-you-use-addeventlistener-for-one-class-to-react-to-the/10496558#10496558)

Comment: I don't get it to work for my class. Does your first example with **Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE** also works if the class comes with a EventDispatcher? `public final class Bcoder extends EventDispatcher
    {` Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is independent of the type of the class that you try to extend.
However if the class is not an Object that you add on Stage you cannot call [e:Event].parent because it is not an Object placed on Stage.
You must then pass the DisplayObject container as in this pastie:
http://pastie.org/3885542
If this works, you can mark this post as solved, or please, tell me more about the code and what you wanna do.